# GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-automated-file-loader-for-bigquery In PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, bigdata, google-bigquery

I am not familiar with java development. I am PHP developer. I want solution for automated file loader for bigquery In PHP like this [enter link description here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-automated-file-loader-for-bigquery/tree/4965e0869363136e1a295ba7a705d192b65306e6)

currently i am using BigQuery REST API using PHP Library working well. looking for the automated solution for ETL and auto uploading the files from cloud storage to BigQuery.

**looking PHP solution for : Data Pipeline** - transforming and loading data into BigQuery.

Any help / suggestions appreciated Thanks in advance....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bigquery + PHP examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413717/bigquery-php-examples)

Comment: This is the example of REST API, I want ETL(Data Pipeline) solution in PHP...