# BigQuery PHP Call to undefined method Google_Client::setAssertionCredentials()

Tags: php, api, google-bigquery

So basically I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413717/bigquery-php-examples) from the second answer, but it comes with an error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Google_Client::setAssertionCredentials() in

Here's my code

```
require_once 'xxx/vendor/autoload.php';
public function createGClient() {
    define("CLIENT_ID", "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com");
    define("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME","xxx@xxx.ccc");
    define("KEY_FILE",'xxx');

    define("PROJECT_ID","xxx");
    define("DATASET_ID","xxx");
    define("TABLE_ID","xxx");

    $this->client = new Google_Client();
    $this->client->setApplicationName("Test");  

    $key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);
    $this->client->setAssertionCredentials(
    Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'), $key, "notasecret"));
    $this->client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
    $this->service = new Google_Service_Bigquery($this->client);
}

public function runQuery() {
    // To see the a list of tables  
    print_r($this->service->tables->listTables(PROJECT_ID, DATASET_ID));

    // To see details of a table
    print_r($this->service->tables->get(PROJECT_ID, DATASET_ID, TABLE_ID));

    // To query a table
    $jobs = $this->service->jobs;
    $query = new Google_Service_Bigquery_QueryRequest();
    $query->setQuery("SELECT * FROM wherever;");
    $response = $jobs->query(PROJECT_ID, $query);
    print_r($response);
}
```

I already install everything from the guide/doc. Can someone help me because I tried everything and it doesnt work, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No longer use that version of the PHP library as it's outdated and lacks documentation.

There is a newer one linked below it works with the need to setup the service account default credentials see lines with `putenv` and `useApplicationDefaultCredentials()`. This is a working code I have using the library https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client You need to obtain your service account key file from the console: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/cloud": "^0.13.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

**php file**

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
use Google\Cloud\ServiceBuilder;

$query="SELECT repository_url, 
       repository_has_downloads 
FROM   [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
LIMIT  10";
$client = new Google_Client();
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.dirname(__FILE__) . '/.ssh/dummyname-7f0004z148e1.json');//this can be created with other ENV mode server side
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$builder = new ServiceBuilder([
                'projectId' => 'edited',
        ]);

        $bigQuery = $builder->bigQuery();

        $job = $bigQuery->runQueryAsJob($query);
        $info=$job->info();
//      print_r($info);
//      exit;
        $queryResults = $job->queryResults();

        /*$queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery(
            $query,
            ['useLegacySql' => true]);*/

        if ($queryResults->isComplete()) 
        {
            $i = 0;
            $rows = $queryResults->rows();

            foreach ($rows as $row) 
            {
                $i++;

                $result[$i] = $row;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            throw new Exception('The query failed to complete');
        }

        print_r($result);
```

Comment: "Fatal error: Class 'Google\Cloud\ServiceBuilder' not found in" Did I miss something?

Comment: Make sure that both composer libraries are properly installed. And of course you need to import `vendor/autoload.php`  for composer to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I reinstalled everything and it works really well.

Comment: Aren't `default credentials` supposed to mean it uses auto-generated GAE and GCE [service accounts' keys](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project)? So no need to generate one and specify as a key-file in  `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`?

Comment: You need to use one and specify it can be the first one in your panel. The PHP library by default it means that if loaded on the server as ENV variables it will try to figure it out. But often if we work with multiple projects we specify per projects in the lib.