# How to access Google Bigquery database with php in 2023?

Tags: javascript, php, server, google-bigquery

Here is my code to access bigquery using php:

```
<?php

echo "hhhh0";

// Check if the autoload file exists
if (!file_exists('vendor/autoload.php')) {
    die('Please run "composer install" to set up the required dependencies.');
}

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

// Replace 'path/to/your/keyfile.json' and 'your-project-id' with actual values
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=weather_839.json');

// Function to run a BigQuery query and return data
function runBigQueryQuery($query)
{
    $projectId = 'weather-839';

    echo "hhhh4";


    $bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
        'projectId' => $projectId,
    ]);

    echo "hhhh5";


    $queryJobConfig = $bigQuery->query($query);

    echo "hhhh6";

    $queryJob = $bigQuery->startQuery($queryJobConfig);

    echo "hhhh7";

    $queryJob->waitUntilComplete();

    if ($queryJob->isComplete()) {
        $queryResults = $queryJob->queryResults();
        $data = [];
        foreach ($queryResults as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Query failed to complete.');
    }
}

echo "hhhh1";

// Example: Run a query and fetch data
$query = 'SELECT * FROM weather.CW_5123 LIMIT 1000';

echo "hhhh2";

$result = runBigQueryQuery($query);


echo "hhhh3";


// Output the result as JSON (or process it as needed)
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo "hhhh4";

echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

here is the error:

hhhh0hhhh1hhhh2hhhh4hhhh5hhhh6

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to bigquery.googleapis.com port 443: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/weather-839/jobs?prettyPrint=false in D:\xampp\htdocs\weather839\vendor\google\cloud\Core\src\RequestWrapper.php:397 Stack trace: 
> #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\weather839\vendor\google\cloud\Core\src\RequestWrapper.php(214): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->convertToGoogleException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException)) 
> #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\weather839\vendor\google\cloud\Core\src\RestTrait.php(102): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) 
> #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\weather839\vendor\google\cloud\BigQuery\src\Connection\Rest.php(241): Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Connection\Rest->send('jobs', 'insert', Array) 
> #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\weather839\vendor\google\cloud\BigQuery\src\BigQueryClient.php(701): Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Connection\Rest->insertJob(Array) 
> #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\weather839\vendor\google\cloud\BigQuery\src\BigQueryClient.php(399): Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient->startJob(Array, Array) 
> #5 D:\xampp\htdocs\weather839\test.php(36): Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient->startQuery(Object(Google\Cloud\BigQuery\QueryJobConfiguration)) 
> #6 D:\xampp\htdocs\weather839\test.php(61): runBigQueryQuery('SELECT * FROM w...') 
> #7 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\weather839\vendor\google\cloud\Core\src\RequestWrapper.php on line 397

Hope I have mentioned clearly, thanks

Comment: There is a reason for the TEXT requirements in asking a question, And its not to repeat the same nonense multiple times

Comment: Is this any help https://stackoverflow.com/a/33025920/2310830